# Yosemite Spotlight Calculator suddenly stopped working

Tags: macos, spotlight

I use Spotlight's Calculator feature occasionally, but I've noticed that it has stopped working recently.  Instead I get a  "No Results" message:

[image: Example calculation not working]

I've verified that Calculator is enabled in Spotlight System Preferences.  Restarting the computer does not help.  I also tried disabling and re-enabling the Calculator setting in Spotlight.

Any other ideas?

Comment: did you try with 0.1 instead of .1

Comment: Just tried, same problem.  Also a problem with just `33*44`

Comment: Any chance you've deleted the calculator app? (Not sure if it makes a difference, but might as well look into it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the spotlight preferences file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Spotlight.plist
```

And then reboot. I was having the same problem and that fixed it for me.

Comment: A day later, with no system changes on my end, the spotlight calculator stopped working again. Have you had similar behavior on your end?

Comment: I ended up calling Apple Support; their solution was to reinstall my operating system. Good times!

Comment: No, mine's been working for about a week now. I hope it stays that way.